# Графическая библиотека python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Нужна библиотека, которая предоставит мне окно MxN пикселей, которые я смогу выборочно закрашивать и обновлять это изображение нное количество раз в секунду. Буду использовать для визуализаций и прочего. В общем что-то вроде pixilang, но как библиотека для python

Comment: Например, через `pyqt5` (`pip install pyqt5`). Вот тут пример ручного рисования на окне с таймером: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/effect_of_vanishing_photos/effect_of_vanishing_photos.py#L98 . Или пример рисования шариков, что сталкиваются об стенки: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/24ca921c776d356382034ee7c0267538733f6df7/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyq5__simple_balls__with_part_transparent_body.py#L117

Comment: pygame, arcade...